# How to capture password from tcpdump pcap result

Tags: telnet, tcpdump

I capture data from telnet using tcpdump. Command:

```
tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r output.pcap
```

Now I need to get plain password after capturing so i try command like this

```
strings output.pcap
```

but this command show me "login:" and "password:" but I don't see data.

[image]

Is it possible to output plain password without using wireshark and other external tools?

Comment: Try `tcpflow` instead of `tcpdump`. Something like `tcpflow -C -r output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to do it using only tcpdump command?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to parse pcap file, I would recommend using tshark. Here's a sample:

Command to capture the telnet tcp port:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'port 23' -w output.pcap
```

Extract the first tcp stream (0) and display in using ascii format:

```
tshark -z follow,tcp,ascii,0 -P -r output.pcap
```

So the result is:

```
        00000176  50 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64  3a                       Password :
0000002F  73                                                s
00000030  6f                                                o
00000031  6d                                                m
00000032  65                                                e
00000033  70                                                p
00000034  61                                                a
00000035  73                                                s
00000036  73                                                s
00000037  77                                                w
00000038  6f                                                o
00000039  72                                                r
0000003A  64                                                d
0000003B  0d 00                                             ..
```

So with some simple parsing, it's possible to find the password there.

Or you can simply use the tcpdupm with -A or-X option

```
tcpdump -A -r  output.pcap

tcpdump -X -r  output.pcap
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with `tcpdump` only? I faced the same issue. The telnet password and username are not readable in the `tcpdump` output.
Why does it not work with `tcpdump` and works with `tshark`?

Comment: Well, you right, it's possible, however requires more parsing, especially it's harder to follow single tcp connection. But something like this should work: tcpdum -i eth0 'tcp port 23' -X

Comment: Yes, you are right 'sudo tcpdump -i eth0 'tcp port 23' -X' works. But how to read from a .pcap file to get the same output?

Comment: According to the manual (https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) option -r should help in this case, so something like this tcpdump -r out.dump 'tcp port 23' -X

Comment: Yeap, thanks, I found the solution too:
 `sudo tcpdump -A -r  .pcap | less` - please add it to your answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the hint. tcpdump is quite a powerful tool